# Copying element nodes to another xml file using xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, copy, xmlstarlet

I want to copy from an xml file, two element nodes to another node (parent) in an existing xml file using xmlstarlet.

input example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<article>
   <publication>
    <title locale="en_US">Ludo-Narrative Dissonance Revisited<title>
    <abstract locale="en_US"> which we see</abstract>     <licenseUrl>https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0</licenseUrl>
    <copyrightHolder>Pawe;zyk, Bo Kampmann Walther</copyrightHolder>
    <copyrightYear>2023</copyrightYear>
    <keywords locale="en_US">
      <keyword>Ludo-narrative dissonance</keyword>
      <keyword>ludology</keyword>
    </keywords>
    <authors xmlns:xsi="http://XMLSchema-instance">
      <author include_in_browse="true">
        <givenname locale="en_US">Pawe</givenname>
        <familyname locale="en_US">Grabarczyk</familyname>
        <affiliation locale="en_US">IT University</affiliation>
      </author>
      <author include_in_browse="true">
        <givenname locale="en_US">Bo</givenname>
        <familyname locale="en_US">Kampmann Walther</familyname>
        <affiliation locale="en_US">University</affiliation>
       </author>
      </authors>
  </publication>
</article>
```

I would like to copy the elements,  and  as child elements to an existing second xml file where <from_old_xml> serves as a parent.  will only contain  and

output.xml will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) Journal Archiving and Interchange DTD v1.2 20190208//EN" "JATS-archivearticle1.dtd"> <article xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" dtd-version="1.2" article-type="other">
  <front>
    <journal-meta>
      <journal-id/>
      <journal-title-group/>
      <issn/>
      <journal-title-group/>
      <publisher>
        <publisher-name/>
      </publisher>
    </journal-meta>
    <article-meta>
      <article-id pub-id-type="doi">10.7557/23.6506</article-id>
      <title-group>
        <article-title>Game of Twisted Shouting</article-title>
        <subtitle>Ludo-Narrative Dissonance Revisited</subtitle>
      </title-group>
      <contrib-group/>
    </article-meta>
    <from_old_xml> 
      <keywords>
        <keyword>Ludo-narrative dissonance</keyword>
        <keyword>ludology</keyword>
        <keyword>narrativity</keyword>
        <keyword>gameplay</keyword>
        <keyword>games and violence</keyword>
      </keywords>
      <authors>
        <author>
          <givenname>Bo</givenname>
          <familyname>Kampmann Walther</familyname>
        </author>
        <author>
          <givenname>Bo</givenname>
          <familyname>Kampmann Walther</familyname>
        </author>
      </authors>
    <from_old_xml> 
  </front>
</article>

xmlstarlet ed -L \
     -s "//article/front" -t test -n "from_old_xml" -v "$(xmlstarlet select --omit-decl -t --copy-of '//article/publication/keywords' input.xml)" output.xml
```

It does not work and I need help.

Thanks in advance

- Ofuuzo

Answer (score 0):

Here we go ^^

```
$ xmlstarlet edit -r '/dataTemplate' -v 'sec' xml1
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<sec>
  <test>John</test>
  <test>Peter</test>
  <test>Paul</test>
</sec>
```

So

```
 $ xmlstarlet edit -r '/dataTemplate' -v 'sec' xml1 | tee xml2
```

Comment: So give a better sample. My answer fulfill your requirements